# skipWaiting() is not installing new service worker which is stuck in waiting phase

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, updating, workbox

I am creating a PWA and I want to prompt user when an updated service worker is available but it get's stuck into waiting phase regardless of whether I call `skipWaiting()` or I manually press `skipWaiting` in dev console.

The new service worker will get installed only if I first stop the existing service worker.

I tried force installation as well by calling `self.skipWaiting()` directly in installation phase but my updated service worker still gets stuck into waiting phase.

This is my setup.

sw.js

```
// when installing hydrate caches and notify user that reload if required (if any)
self.addEventListener('install', async () => {
    // self.skipWaiting();
    await hydrateCache();
});

self.addEventListener('message', (message) => {
    if (message.data === 'skipWaiting') {
        debugger;
        self.skipWaiting();
    }
});
```

index.html

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
  .then(function (reg) {
     reg.onupdatefound = function() {
       var newServiceWorker = reg.installing;

       if (reg.waiting && confirm('Updates are available, Would you like to reload?')) {
          newServiceWorker.postMessage('skipWaiting');
       }

       newServiceWorker.onstatechange = function() {
         // for some reason I am not getting waiting state update so I am prompting user
         // when client gets installed phase update
         if (newServiceWorker.state === 'installed') {
           if (confirm('Updates are available, Would you like to reload?')) {
             newServiceWorker.postMessage('skipWaiting');
           }
         }
       }
     }

     navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', function() {
       window.location.reload();
     });        
   })
   .catch(function (err) {
     console.error('register err', err);
   });
```

I am expecting that whenever I send `skipWaiting` message to service worker it should replace existing serviceWorker, my code does call `self.skipWaiting()` but in dev console my updated service worker still stays in waiting phase and even if I manually press `skipWaiting` it does not replace the existing service worker.

[image: current-website]

**UPDATE:**

so after tinkering with my code I found one interesting thing, something from my `'fetch'` event handler is preventing my updated service worker to get activated even though I called `skipWaiting()` call.

This code will not let the new service worker get activated

```
// intercept fetch requests and responds with cached file if they are available like CDN Files
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response) {
                    console.log('Found ', event.request.url, ' in cache');
                    return response;
                }

                console.log('fetching', event.request.url, 'from internet');
                return fetch(event.request);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error('fetch error', err);
            }),
    );
});
```

If I remove my custom code from the `'fetch'` even handler, my updated service worker will get activated when I call `skipWaiting()`. I'm basically not doing anything with my `'fetch'` handler as soon as my worker intercepts a request it'll directly try to get it from internet.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    return fetch(event.request);
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348907/service-worker-skipwaiting-unable-to-activate-currently-waiting-sw looks similar to this issue, check it out might help

Comment: Hi, I've already checked that post and made changes based on that (I have already commented on the accepted answer of that question), but still I don't get my service worker registered even if I forcefully do it as in install event callback.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Btw, I think `return fetch(event.request);` should be `event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));` ? Not that either works for me ..

Comment: Happened to me, too, and turned out to be a Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1175696 I also posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031376/service-worker-doesnt-skip-waiting-state