# service worker doesn't skip waiting state

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, service-worker-events

I'm still doing experiments in order to master service workers, and I'm facing a problem, probably because of my lack of expertise in JavaScript and service workers.

The problem happens when I want the new service worker to `skipWaiting()` using `postMessage()`. If I show a popup with a button and I bind a call to `postMessage()` there, everything works. If I call `postMessage()` directly, it doesn't work. It's a race condition because **SOMETIMES** it works, but I can't identify the race condition.

BTW, the `postMessage()` call WORKS, the service worker is logging what it should when getting the message:

```
// Listen to messages from clients.
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    switch(event.data) {
        case 'skipWaiting': self.skipWaiting(); console.log('I skipped waiting... EXTRA');
            break;
    }
});
```

Here is the code. The important bit is on the `if (registration.waiting)` conditional. The uncommented code works, the commented one doesn't:

```
// Register service worker.
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // Helpers to show and hide the update toast.
    let hideUpdateToast = () => {
        document.getElementById('update_available').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    };

    let showUpdateToast = (serviceworker) => {
        document.getElementById('update_available').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('force_install').onclick = () => {
            serviceworker.postMessage('skipWaiting');
            hideUpdateToast();
        };
        document.getElementById('close').onclick = () => hideUpdateToast();
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {

        let refreshing = false;
        navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
            if (refreshing) return;
            refreshing = true;
            window.location.reload();
        });

        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(registration => {
            // A new service worker has been fetched, watch for state changes.
            //
            // This event is fired EVERY TIME a service worker is fetched and
            // succesfully parsed and goes into 'installing' state. This
            // happens, too, the very first time the page is visited, the very
            // first time a service worker is fetched for this page, when the
            // page doesn't have a controller, but in that case there's no new
            // version available and the notification must not appear.
            //
            // So, if the page doesn't have a controller, no notification shown.
            registration.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
                // return;  // FIXME
                registration.installing.onstatechange = function () {  // No arrow function because 'this' is needed.
                    if (this.state == 'installed') {
                        if (!navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                            console.log('First install for this service worker.');
                        } else {
                            console.log('New service worker is ready to activate.');
                            showUpdateToast(this);
                        }
                    }
                };
            });

            // If a service worker is in 'waiting' state, then maybe the user
            // dismissed the notification when the service worker was in the
            // 'installing' state or maybe the 'updatefound' event was fired
            // before it could be listened, or something like that. Anyway, in
            // that case the notification has to be shown again.
            //
            if (registration.waiting) {
                console.log('New service worker is waiting.');
                // showUpdateToast(registration.waiting);

                // The above works, but this DOESN'T WORK.
                registration.waiting.postMessage('skipWaiting');
            }

        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('Service worker registration failed!');
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Why does the indirect call using a button `onclick` event works, but calling `postMessage()` doesn't?

I'm absolutely at a loss and I bet the answer is simple and I'm just too blind to see it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Clearly a race condition, the commented code works perfectly if I add a timeout there...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes  works out of the box. If you do not use workbox ,consider doing so ( time to learn it , but covers caching and SW registration, updates , race conds all very well.)

Comment: Thanks Robert, but the key here is to understand why all this is happening :) I know I can use Workbox, but I want to learn all this subject of service workers as deeply as I can and understand why things happen. In production I may use Workbox, it's easier for me.  Also, I don't want to use a banner or other UI element. That already works like a charm with my code, I want to know why the other option, the "direct route", doesn't work...

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/8ffe56090f712e9b8bb6cff14e25f7ec090a1ce4/packages/workbox-core/src/skipWaiting.ts#L22-L26  - same issue as u mentioned in WB prior version .. may be useful to you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, Robert, but that doesn't look like my problem. Maybe I'm not finding the issue, but the ones I've checked all go in the same direction: some service worker blocked by a SSE or a websocket connection, but that's not my case, I've checked. BTW, this only happens in webkit, all other browsers I've used work perfectly, so maybe it's a webkit problem, I don't know...

Comment: way down in weeds but worth reading Posnick here : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2199#issuecomment-524335980

Comment: I'm sorry, Robert, but I don't get it. What does that comment have to do with the problem I was pointing? I mean, the main problem I'm having is that the Promise returned by `skipWaiting()` doesn't resolve, the function blocks for some reason on webkit unless I add a delay, while the post you link is talking about something I already know, you can watch for events in both service workers and you will get both state changes... Anyway, thanks, because the sources of Workbox are being quite informative, even though that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Would you please explain how you solve this issue with timeout? I have the same problem and I need to skipWaiting to be sure new version is available to all my users as soon as possible and this issue is making a lot of problem for us!

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Mehrnoosh. The delay/timeout is added in the code above, in the service worker. Instead of calling `self.skipWaiting()` directly, do it like `setTimeout(self.skipWaiting, 100)`. You may need to adjust the timeout, and it's a hack I don't like, but it worked. Right now I'm not using that, I'm just calling `self.skipWaiting()` directly on the service worker's `install` handler. Brutal but it works for me and for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into exactly the same issue. Turns out `skipWaiting` never resolves if it's called on an installed service worker while there's still a pending fetch request on the active service worker. Funnily enough the active service worker is reloaded once the request settles, so this is clearly a bug with Chrome. That's also the reason why it only happens sometimes and why a timeout or a delayed request for `skipWaiting` has a higher chance to succeed, especially if it's called upon page load.

So you'll want to wait for all open network requests to settle before calling `skipWaiting`. Maybe someone else is more creative, but I've found two ways to prevent the race condition:

1. If your application only ever has one client, you can monkey-patch `XMLHttpRequest` to track open network requests and hold back the request for `skipWaiting` until all requests are settled.
2. If there are multiple clients you'll want to introduce a "shutdown" routine which will make the active SW defer all new fetch requests (`return false` instead of `respondWith` in your fetch handler) while waiting for all open requests to be settled upon which you can safely call `skipWaiting` in your installed SW.

It's a bit much, but the only way I was able to prevent my app from sporadically running into this using Chrome.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because, even though is a bug in Chrome (and it is still unfixed, as far as I know) your workarounds look suitable for me (number 2, at least). Thanks A LOT for the suggestion. I'm not developing that code anymore but at some point I will have to go back and I'll try to implement your solution. Thanks A LOT, really, Mario.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in Chromium or WebKit, because this code works all the time in Firefox but fails in Chrome and Edge most of the time.

I've reported that bug to Chromium, let's see if it is a bug or my code is weird. I've managed to build the smallest code possible that still reproduces the issue, it's quite small and it can be found on the bug report.

The report can be found [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1175696).

Sorry for the noise, I'll keep investigating the issue but no matter how I tried, the code still fails from time to time, I can't spot the race condition on my code.

Comment: Please update if you have found an answer to this. I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you can see from the report, the bug is not even triaged yet. What I've done in my PWA is aggressively take control of the page whenever a new service worker can be installed. But that's a luxury I can afford in MY PWA, other PWAs wouldn't... If a solution happens, ever (it's Google, not famous for fixing bugs) I'll update my reply.

Comment: You're welcome, but I didn't do anything, the bug is still not triaged, I don't think it will ever be fixed, and the solution I proposed was too aggressive for a generic PWA. Anyway, thanks for your comment, Ariart :)